# What are the steps needed to crack one password stored in a web app

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

If I am an attacker and I just ex-filtrated the web-based user database via SQL injection (including the per user salt) and I want to target ONE password of interest,  what are the steps given:

1. I have an infinite amount of time to wait
2. I have the fastest cpu's available

(I.E I don't care about the best way of doing this, just wanting to know the how to do it this way)

It seems like:

1. Identify the password "hashing" algo (bcrypt/scrypt/argon2)
2. Identify the salt associated with the hashed password of interest
3. Identify the number of rounds of hashing used. (how to do so?)
4. Finally run this through some sort of rainbow table generator/program to create the lookup table.

Am I far off here?

Comment: Generally the hash/salt themselves are stored in a format that identifies the algo, the salt, and the number of rounds. Programs like Hashcat and JTR are often able to automatically detect the type based on this.

Comment: No table generation. For 1 password, just start hashing passwords, going from most to least likely.

Comment: Exactly as @NeilSmithline says. Unless you have access to the salt beforehand and are able to precompute a table, you should just do it in realtime.

Comment: @forest - good point to clarify - that's what I meant but did not convey very well. Also this seems like a good answer if you want to 'officially' answer. Thanks!

Comment: Most of the time attacker can use the normal UI to create an account for himself with a known password and they can use that known account to verify that the assumptions made about the hash are correct. Then the attacker starts guessing one password after another until a correct one is found (easy to do since you have "infinite amount of time to wait").